# Search filter strange issue in ListView

Tags: android, listview, search, android-listview, parse-platform

I've got a problem with search filter. I've got a custom ListView with image and few Strings. When I start to search the searched object appears, but the other Strings in ListView stay in the same position. I attach pictures, so you can see it batter. Do you have any idea, how to solve this? Thanks a lot :) (codes are below)

My ListView before search:
[image: description]

My ListView after search:
[image: description]

My Adapter:

```
    public class AnimalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Animal> implements Filterable{
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Animal> mAnimals;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    Activity activity;
    AnimalAdapter adapter;
    private Filter animalFilter;
    private List<Animal> animaly;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public AnimalAdapter(Context context, List<Animal> objects) {
          super(context, R.layout.animal_row_item, objects);


          ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).build();

          imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.init(config);
            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc()
            .build();

            this.mContext = context;
            this.mAnimals = objects;
            this.animaly = objects;

      }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
          if(convertView == null){
              LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
              convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.animal_row_item, null);
          }


          final Animal animal = mAnimals.get(position);


          TextView animalView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.animal_text);
          TextView areaView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.area_text);

          final ImageView animalPic = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.animal_pic);
          final ProgressBar indicator = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress);

          indicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          animalPic.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            //Setup a listener we can use to switch from the loading indicator to the Image once it's ready
            ImageLoadingListener listener = new ImageLoadingListener(){



                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String arg0, View arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String arg0, View arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View arg1, Bitmap arg2) {
                    indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    animalPic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String arg0, View view, FailReason arg2) {


                }

            };

          imageLoader.displayImage(getItem(position).getImgUrl(), animalPic,options, listener);
          animalView.setText(animal.getAnimal());
          areaView.setText(animal.getArea());


          convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MoreActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra("about", animal.getAbout());
                    intent.putExtra("animal", animal.getAnimal());
                    intent.putExtra("imgUrl", animal.getImgUrl());
                    getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
          });

          return convertView;
      }




     public int getCount() {
         return mAnimals.size();


     @Override
     public Filter getFilter() {
             if (animalFilter == null)
                     animalFilter = new AnimalFilter();

             return animalFilter;
 }
 }

     private class AnimalFilter extends Filter {



         @Override
         protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

             FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                 // We implement here the filter logic
                 if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                         // No filter implemented we return all the list
                         results.values = animaly;
                         results.count = animaly.size();

                 }
                 else {
                         // We perform filtering operation
                         List<Animal> nAnimalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();
                         final int count = nAnimalList.size();
                         for (Animal p : mAnimals) {
                                 if (p.getAnimal().toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()).startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))

                                     nAnimalList.add(p);


                         }

                         results.values = nAnimalList;
                         results.count = nAnimalList.size();  
                 }
                 return results;
         }

         @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
         protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                         FilterResults results) {

                 // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
                 if (results.count == 0)
                         notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                 else {
                         mAnimals = (List<Animal>) results.values;
                         notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }

         }

 }


}
```

Animal.java

```
@ParseClassName("Animal")
public class Animal extends ParseObject{

    public Animal(){

      }

      public String getAnimal(){
          return getString("animal");
      }

      public void setAnimal(String animal){
          put("animal", animal);
      }

      public String getArea(){
          return getString("area");
      }

      public void setArea(String area){
          put("area", area);
      }

      public String getImgUrl(){
          return getString("imgUrl");
      }

      public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl){
          put("imgUrl", imgUrl);
      }

      public String getAbout(){
          return getString("about");
      }

      public void setAbout(String about){
          put("about", about);
      }

}
```

MainActivity.java (not too important right now i think)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    private ListView mListView;
    private AnimalAdapter mAdapter;
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    EditText mEditText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Add your initialization code here
        Parse.initialize(this, "code", "code");
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Animal.class);
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        header.setPadding(2, 8, 4, 2);



        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.animal_list);
        mListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        mListView.addHeaderView(header);


        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById (R.id.loading_animals);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);





        RemoteDataTask task = new RemoteDataTask();
        task.execute();




    }








     public void updateData(){


         ParseQuery<Animal> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Animal.class);
      query.setCachePolicy(CachePolicy.CACHE_THEN_NETWORK);
    query.orderByAscending("animal");
      query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Animal>() {

          @Override
          public void done(List<Animal> animals, ParseException error) {

              if(animals != null){
                  mAdapter.clear();
               mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              for (int i = 0; i < animals.size(); i++) {

                      mAdapter.add(animals.get(i));


                  }


              }



          }
      });
    }


     @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }


         public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_refresh:
                    Intent refreshIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    refreshIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    refreshIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                    startActivity(refreshIntent);
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                         return true; 
                 } 
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
         }



         private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {




             @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    // Create a progressdialog





                }


             @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                    updateData();


                    return null;
                }


             @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                 mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.animal_list);
                    // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
                 mAdapter = new AnimalAdapter(MainActivity.this, new ArrayList<Animal>());


                    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

                    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_animal);
                      mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
                                int start, int count, int after) {
                            mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                int before, int count) {
                            mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            System.out.println("Text ["+s+"]");
                            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());  


                        }
                    });

                      }

             }

         }
```

Comment: Share your notifyDataSetChanged method. Also, why don't you fill your ListView again? Remove existing and create new after search.

Comment: I dont have notifyDataSetChanged method defined. How do you mean it with adding the ListView again? like mAdapter.clear() etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it. I only changed `imageLoader.displayImage(getItem(position).getImgUrl(), animalPic,options, listener);` to `imageLoader.displayImage(animaly.getImgUrl(), animalPic,options, listener);`

Comment: Just to add: this type of error usually happens due to intrinsic performance optimizations of adapters. Most implementations in the web attempt to recycle views not to spam findViewByID and make ListView super-slow. This ends up in the programmer having to do a lot of View "memory management" for complex item layouts, and to explicitly detail in getView when to allow reusage OR creation of new views entirely, more often than not individually, to the children of the layout itself. Protip: keep ListView rows as simple as possible